# How can I store a list of references in Perl?

Tags: perl, persistence

I would like to create a list of records. I can add one record just fine:

```
my $records = [
  { ID => 5342755,
    NAME => 'Me',
  } ,
 ];
```

When I try to add another record, the other records disappear:

```
$records = [  { 
  ID => 1212121, 
 } ];
```

What is the problem and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm also going to recommend you read over the perl reference tutorial: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: Also, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Comment: @Kitty2 All of those documents are also installed on your computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you are overwritting the value of `$record` so that there is only ever one value in the array. Perhaps try the following instead:

```
my $records = [
  { ID => 5342755,
    NAME => 'Me',
  } ,
 ];

push @$records, { 
  ID => 1212121, 
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You override your variable...

When you declare:

```
my $records = [date structure here];
```

you really declare an array ref, if you are a newbie then try (more intuitive)

```
my @records = (  
               { 
                 ID => 54321,
                 NAME => 'bar',
                } ,
);

push @records, {ID => 12345, NAME => 'foo'};
print $records[1]->{NAME};
```

That would print 'foo'